# writing of htaccess file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, .htaccess

I put in production a website on O2switch.  My backend is Nodejs is in a folder named api in the root of the hosting.  the frontend written in VueJs is placed in a folder named www.  The host asks me to write a .htaccess file but I don't know if I should put it in the root of the FTP or in the www folder.

Locally, when I type [www.monsite.com/page1](http://www.monsite.com/page1) I normally access page 1. On the other hand, online, this page is not available.  Yet the link in the menu works well and provides access to page 1. Could someone help me set up this .htaccess file?

Comment: I find the answer : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>